# Dynamic collection of classes

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

It works, but I don't know how:
I want to create a dynamic number of classes, so I use a dictionary for that.
But I can't add a key to each class of the dictionary.
It works when I add each entry of the 1st dictionary to a second dictionary as a couple item/key.

```
sub test()
Dim dict As New Dictionary
Dim dict2 As New Dictionary

For i = 1 To 2
    Set dict(i) = New Cfgadress
    dict(i).Col1 = i
    dict2.Add "d" & i, dict(i)
Next i

Debug.Print dict2("d1").Col1
Debug.Print dict2("d2").Col1
End Sub
```

That was a guess and I'm not sure I understand how it works : is the entry of the first dictionary a class object, while the entry of the second dictionary is a dictionary object (couple item/key) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for the second dictionary. What's the error you're getting with using just one?

Here is my working code:

Add Module: `Module1`

```
Sub test()

    Dim col1 As Dictionary

    Dim classInstance As Class1

    Dim counter As Long

    ' Init the collection
    Set col1 = New Dictionary

    For counter = 1 To 2

        ' Set new instance of class
        Set classInstance = New Class1

        ' Set properties in new class instance
        classInstance.testfield = "Test value" & counter

        ' Add it to the collection
        col1.Add "test" & counter, classInstance

    Next counter


    Debug.Print col1.Item("test1").testfield
    Debug.Print col1.Item("test2").testfield

End Sub
```

Class: `Class1`

```
Public testfield As String
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I get it, correct me if I'm wrong.

When I create a dictionary entry with

```
Set dict(i) = New Cfgadress
```

It creates a new dictionary entry: blank object of class Cfgadress associated to the key i

Dict(i) refers to the item contained in entry i of the dictionary dict, i.e. to the class object contained.

To change the key, I need to assign a new couple item/key, but the item exists only as entry i of the dictionnary. So I need either :

- to use the entry of the dictionary as an item associated with a key in a new dictionary/collection/array (what I did in my code)
- or to assign dict(i) to an object, add it to the with a correct key and remove the former one.

```
Set object as New class
Set object=dict(i)
dict.Add "key", object
dict.remove "1"
```

Did I get it ?

Your solution is way simpler and that's what I tried first, but I went to dynamic dictionary because on each iteration, updating the class instance was also updating the previous entries of the collection

```
Set Wb = ThisWorkbook           '==================
Set WsCfg = Wb.Sheets("Cfg")    '==================


Dim dict_cfg As New Dictionary
Dim coll As New Collection
Set tcfg_adress = New Cfgadress

For i = 3 To 4 '22

    If WsCfg.Cells(i, 10) = 1 And WsCfg.Cells(i, 11) = 1 Then   
        tcfg_adress.Row1 = WsCfg.Cells(i, 4).Value
        tcfg_adress.Col1 = WsCfg.Cells(i, 5).Value
        tcfg_adress.Lrow = WsCfg.Cells(i, 6).Value
        tcfg_adress.Lcol = WsCfg.Cells(i, 7).Value
        tcfg_adress.Nbrow = WsCfg.Cells(i, 8).Value
        tcfg_adress.Nbcol = WsCfg.Cells(i, 9).Value
        coll.Add tcfg_adress, WsCfg.Cells(i, 1)

     End If
Next i
```

Turns out that setting a new class instance in each loop, as I saw you did in your code, solved my problem. I thought there was nothing to do and was investigating in get arounds. Thanks a lot !